# Create TermsQuery with List<String> using elasticsearch java api client

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch, builder, apiclient

I have an elastic search query as below.

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must_not":{
                  "terms":{
                     "names":[
                        "john",
                        "jose"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to build something like this in the code corresponding to the query.

```
BoolQuery.Builder builder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
List<String> names = ["john","jose"];
TermsQueryField field = new TermsQueryBuilder().value(names).build();
builder.mustNot(TermsQuery.of(t -> t.field("names").terms(field))._toQuery());
```

But I am getting error in this line as it is expecting List of FieldValue inside value function and not List of String.

```
TermsQueryField field = new TermsQueryBuilder().value(names).build();
```

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use below code to create `fieldValues` for your `names`

```
List<FieldValue> fieldValues = names.stream().map(FieldValue::of).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following:

`new TermsQueryField(names.Select(name => FieldValue.String(name)).ToList())`